# Open a byte[] as a file From a javaapplication, User should not be able to edit the file

Tags: java, file-io

I am currently opening the file like this:

```
File f = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
f = FileUtil.writeBytes(b.getBlob(), f);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
```

Context description :
The file is stored on a server. When you want to view the file the byte[] is retrieved from the server and is put in a File object (see line 2 of code sample above).
Now when the user opens the file (for instance txt file) it is possible to edit and save the file (it does not even ask for a fileName, because you have given when creating the File based on the blob in the above sample).
However I don't want this behaviour. I want the file save to behave as 'save as" similar to a non existing file.

In short:

I have :

- A byte[] containing content of a .txt that is located on a server

I want

- To be able to open the file in the associated program (notepad for instance) without actually creating the File on the client PC. When the user would press save, it should be prompted for a fileName, just like when saving a new file for the first time.

How should I go about this?

Example of behaviour I want: behaviour as Mail attachment in email client like thunderbird for example. When clicking on txt attachment it asks me to a)open with ... , or b) save to ... . If i choose open with, and then in text editor I choose save, it prompts me for a name and location.

Comment: The client side of the application runs in the client browser (web-based application), right? Or the client side is a desktop application?

Comment: Why don't you just show the text inside a HTML page of your application, instead of sending it as an attachment? In the title you say the user should not be able to edit the file.

Comment: Depending on the editor you use, it may suffice to mark the file read only with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean)

Comment: @EricNielsen, it is a Desktop application, also the attachment could be a txt, a word doc, a pdf etc...

Comment: @mihi, Does not seem to work i can still edit and save the file (without being prompted for location)

Comment: @ruben056 perhaps `File.setReadOnly` (after writing the file contents of course) works better for you? Anyway, none of these options can prevent an application to save the file, they are just hints that some applications use to open "save as" dialogs...

Comment: @mihi, the setReadOnly didn't work, but your first suggestion setWriteable(false) dit work after all. Now user is prompted to "save as".

Answer (score 2):

Undoable. Even if you, a bit after opening the temporary file, would delete the file, for instance Notepad would not see it. Others would ask to recreate at the same spot.

Would an alternative not suffice: first a "create new" - a file save dialog -, you create the file where desired, and then do a Desktop.open.

Comment: I actually don't even want the file to be saved on the disk locally, I just want to open the file. Ideally i pass a byte[] and extensions and the correct program is openen based on extension and content is added using byte[].

Comment: @ruben056: there is no "file" unless you save it to a disk locally. You *could* possibly save the file to a disk on the *server* and let the client open it (assuming the client has access to/mounted a file share on the server), but that's fragile as it requires additional setup.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I know, hence the description with byte[] as content and extension to let Desktop know which program to open. I do not want to open the share to all client pc's , I would not be passing the byte[] content around if I did :).

Comment: Another alternative: **copy-to-clipboard**. One may place in the clipboard several mime types, together: plain text, styled text, images ... Make a button "save to clipboard". As does 'character map.'